# Xcode muestra los errores por muy poco tiempo o directamente no muestra nada

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Recientemente actualice a Xcode 14.3 la ultima lanzada por apple y me encontre con este problema en el que los errores parpadean por demasiado poco tiempo y eso en el mejor de los casos en la mayoría ni siquiera salen.

Descargue la version anterior que me funcionaba bien pero ahora tampoco con esa version me funciona, reinstale, cambie lo de rosetta pero nada de eso me funciono, incluso reinicio la maquina pero nada funciono.

Comment: Sin un ejemplo es imposible ayudar, as revisado los "release notes"? Calvez haya un cambio q afecte tu proyecto. Suena como algo de tiempo, puede ser q haya un refresh q no estas tomando en consideración.

Answer (score 0):

Como dicen en comentarios sería necesaria un poco mas de información con respecto a tu problema, como una evidencia visual. Aun así si me ocurriera algo parecido seguiría estos pasos.

1. Limpiar el caché de xCode (shift + Comand + k)
2. Limpiar el Derived Data (Con aplicaciones como devCleaner es un proceso muy sencillo)
3. Reiniciar el Equipo
4. Si todo lo demás no funciona, reinstalar xCode
5. Reinstalar el sistema operativo o actualizarlo.

Espero que alguna de estas opciones te sirvan.